# Trouble with SKAction.runBlock running in sequence

Tags: swift, skaction

I have several runBlocks that i need to run in sequence, but find they even when using SKAction.sequence([action1, action2, action3]) they still run concurrently.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here is an example of my code:

```
func SetupText() {

    let wait = SKAction.waitForDuration(2.0)

    var Label1 = SKLabelNode()
    Label1.fontColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    Label1.position = CGPointMake(self.size.width / 2.3, self.size.height / 1.4)
    Label1.text = "blah1"
    self.addChild(Label1)
    scrollLabel1 = SKAction.runBlock({
        self.runSomeCode(Label1)
    })

    var Label2 = SKLabelNode()
    Label2.fontColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    Label2.position = CGPointMake(self.size.width / 2.5, self.size.height * 0.6)
    Label2.text = "blah2"
    self.addChild(Label2)
    scrollLabel2 = SKAction.runBlock({
        self.runSomeCode(Label2)
    })

    var Label3 = SKLabelNode()
    Label3.fontColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    Label3.position = CGPointMake(self.size.width / 2.5, self.size.height * 0.5)
    Label3.text = "blah3"
    self.addChild(Label3)
    scrollLabel3 = SKAction.runBlock({
        self.runSomeCode(Label3)
    })

    var Label4 = SKLabelNode()
    Label4.fontColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    Label4.position = CGPointMake(self.size.width / 2.5, self.size.height * 0.4)
    Label4.text = "blah4"
    self.addChild(Label4)
    scrollLabel4 = SKAction.runBlock({
        self.runSomeCode(Label4)
    })

    var Label5 = SKLabelNode()
    Label5.fontSize = 20
    Label5.fontName = "LiquidCrystal-Regular"
    Label5.fontColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    Label5.position = CGPointMake(self.size.width / 2.5, self.size.height * 0.3)
    Label5.text = "blah5"
    self.addChild(Label5)
    scrollLabel5 = SKAction.runBlock({
        self.runSomeCode(Label5)
    })

    var actions = Array<SKAction>()
    actions.append(wait)
    actions.append(scrollLabel1)
    actions.append(scrollLabel2)
    actions.append(scrollLabel3)
    actions.append(scrollLabel4)
    actions.append(scrollLabel5)
    let sequence = SKAction.sequence(actions)

    self.runAction(sequence)

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually it seems there is nothing to do with actions, but it's about the run blocks. The run blocks can have actions take longer than the sequence, which means your sequence will seem concurrent. Using regular actions instead of action blocks needs to solve your problem.

Comment: I don't think the regular actions will accomplish my custom label animation.  is there a way to run these blocks synchronously?

Comment: You can use performSelector for your named actions and use the completion handler to call the next one.

Comment: That yields the same result unless I am doing something wrong.  I created a  function called scrollText() to set up the action and call a subsequent action in completion handler for the selector **self.runAction(scrollLabel1, completion: {self.runAction(self.scrollLabel2)})** then call it in my performSelector like this **performSelector(Selector(self.scrollText()), withObject: self, afterDelay: 2.0)**